# Intersitial Ads not loading Android?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have intersitial ads but not calling load method it gives following warning in logcat:

```
11-04 09:32:02.046: I/Ads(29747): No fill from ad server.
11-04 09:32:02.066: W/Ads(29747): Failed to load ad: 3
```

My banner ads are loading but failing with Intersitial ads.

Following code was written for this:

```
AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onAdLoaded();
        interstitial.show();
    }
});
```

Help

Comment: No fill from ad server.. this error is from their side .. currently no ad in their db. have you declared the unit id properly in your code in the xml too. try cleaning and re installing the app again

Comment: yes adUnitId is proper banner ads used same ID working fine but for interestial ads not loading

Comment: have you checked this link https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial

Comment: There is no issues in your code. I think there might be some problem in loading the ad from server. Try again after few mins..

Comment: so i need to have different ad unit id for intersitial ads and banner ads.

Comment: Have you added this in manifest...  
<!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

Comment: try downloading the code of google and add your id into it and check it out https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/interstitial/src/com/google/example/gms/ads/advanced

Comment: yes i have done config .. test ads were working fine.. now banner only works not intersitial ads

Comment: Then try creating a different ad unit id for interstital.. i did this long back. couldn't get it right :)

Comment: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob/issues/120 you are right.. need to create two id's for sure

Comment: Don't call interstitial#show from onAdLoaded. It provides poor user experience and is likely to get your account banned. Call #show from a natural break point in your app instead.

Comment: i am calling at break point only when download is complete of specific things :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Solution was you need to different Ad Unit ids for Banner and Intersitial Ads. For test device its fine to use one but for production you need to different ad units id.

[Link](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob/issues/120) for solution.

Answer (score -1):

this is my intersitial ads example just need to refract code whatever you want:

```
public class InterstitialsAdsExampleActivity extends Activity implements
        AdListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAds = null;
    private TextView textView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this,"your ad-id here");
        this.interstitialAds.setAdListener(this);

        Button loadButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
        loadButton.setOnClickListener(loadButtonOnClick);

        this.textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.stateTextView);
    }

    private OnClickListener loadButtonOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.setText("Loading Intertitial Ads");

            AdRequest adr = new AdRequest();
            // add your test device here
            //adr.addTestDevice("your test device id here");
            interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode error) {
        String message = "Load Ads Failed: (" + error + ")";
        textView.setText(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * Called when an Activity is created in front of the app (e.g. an
     * interstitial is shown, or an ad is clicked and launches a new Activity).
     */
    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
        if (interstitialAds.isReady()) {
            interstitialAds.show();
        } else {
            textView.setText("Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown.");
        }
    }
}
```